# Invalid cast exception for an object of the correct type?

Tags: .net, exception, casting, com, office-interop

Please help me understand what's happening here.

---

### Here is my code:

```
Dim DocProps As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties
Dim WeekName As String = StartDate.ToString("yyMMdd") & "_" & EndDate.ToString("yyMMdd")
Dim PropName As String = "Log Week"
DocProps = WeeklyReports.CustomDocumentProperties
```

I get an invalid cast exception on the last line which says:

> "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{2DF8D04D-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

---

### The documentation says:

I'm trying to access the [CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.customdocumentproperties.aspx) member of a workbook so that I can check the value of a property.

The documentation says:

> Returns or sets a [DocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms250653) collection that represents all
>   the custom document properties for the specified workbook.

---

### Why I'm confused:

This object seems to have a chameleon type.  Here is what I've done to try to track down what it is:

```
Dim DocProps As Object
DocProps = WeeklyReports.CustomDocumentProperties
Debug.Print(DocProps Is Nothing)
Debug.Print(TypeName(DocProps))
Debug.Print(TypeOf(DocProps) is DocumentProperties)
Debug.Print(GetType(DocumentProperties).AssemblyQualifiedName)
Debug.Print(DocProps.GetType.ToString)    
Debug.Print(vbNewLine)

For Each InterfaceType As Type In GetType(DocumentProperties).GetInterfaces
        Debug.Print(InterfaceType.ToString)
    Next

DirectCast(DocProps, Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)
DocProps.Add(Name:=PropName,
             LinkToContent:=False,
             Type:=MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
             Value:=WeekName)
```

I get the following results in my output window.

> False
>   DocumentProperties
>   False
>   Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties, Office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
>   System.__ComObject
>
> System.Collections.IEnumerable

So from this we can see there seems to be some conflicting information about this object's type.

The `TypeName()` function returns "DocumentProperties", while `.GetType` just sees it as a COM object, and while I can't tell what `TypeOf()` sees, it certainly doesn't see it as a match with `Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties`.

Next we see what interfaces this crazy object implements, and the only one revealed to us is the IEnumerable interface.

So we get to the next line where I tried to use `DirectCast` and I get the same InvalidCast Exception as our original code. So it appears we can trust this `GetInterfaces` method because clearly this object doesn't implement the `DocumentProperties` interface or we would be able to cast it as such type, right?  Right????

Well......maybe because in the last test, I found another anomaly further obfuscating this object's true type; if I skip over the `DirectCast` attempt and go right to the `.Add` method of the object without casting it as any type, it succeeds.  Now, there is no `.Add` method of the IEnumerable interface - so where the heck is this coming from?  And for that matter, where did the `TypeName` come from if it's not of the type `DocumentProperties` as all the other tests seem to indicate???

---

### So what gives?

There is only one namespace in the entire project with a "DocumentsProperties" member - I simply typed the fully qualified name for clarity, not out of necessity. This IS the correct namespace for the object per the documentation. (see above links)

When I experimented with weak typing, I got what seemed to be contradicting information on the type of this object.  When I skipped over the `DirectCast` line I was able to successfully execute the `.Add` method of this object. The fact that I can call this method using the parameter names defined for the `DocumentProperties` interface, coupled with the `TypeName` result seem to indicate that I *do* have an object typed as this interface, however the `TypeOf` comparison and `DirectCast` and implicit casting exceptions indicate I do not.

***My object looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, so why does it refuse to be cast as a duck??***

Comment: Could it be that you are using Interop objects instead of Core? They have almost the same interface, but their IIDs are different. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.customdocumentproperties.aspx

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro.  I am using excel interop objects. The MSDN library entry for [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.customdocumentproperties.aspx) provides a direct link to [Mircosoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms250653) saying this is what is set/get by this property.  Further, no DocumentProperty or DocumentProperties exist within the Excel interop namespace to be confused with, so I have to believe the MSDN is correct here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check that it was actually the same IID. You are right, there is no confusion about names or IIDs. But now I see that you are trying to cast the object as an interface. Shouldn't you use the QueryInterface function to achieve that? Sorry if this is nonsense, I am not fluent in type declarations.

Comment: DirectCast should be able to cast the object as any type which it inherits/implements. That is what's so confusing to me; `TypeName()` tells me this object is of type "DocumentProperties" and it *does* have the `.Add` method from this interface available, but it reports as "False" using `TypeOf()` to compare it to the `DocumentProperties` type, and trying to cast it as this type fails.  Further, using `TypeOf(<t>).GetInterfaces` only returns IEnumerable -which does not have a `.Add` member.

Comment: I will continue, since nobody else seems to have answered you. As I understand it, you have an object whose type is IEnumerable, subclass of IDispatch. That allows you to call methods of DocumentProperties using the IDispatch mechanism to invoke, it even may answer the type name with the dispatched interface, but not being that type nor cast-able to it. As I told you, I am not versed in this, because I use Smalltalk and for me, the IDispatch are just pointers to external memory that answer a vTable and some API calls know how to use for getting the behavior.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro - So the object implements `IDispatch`.  Which means at runtime what's actually happening when I call `.Add` is the `IDispatch.Invoke` method calls the `DocumentProperties.Add` method from the Dispatched interface.  However, the object itself does not necessarily implement the `DocumentProperties` interface, which is why I get the seemingly conflicting results above.  Am I interpreting you correctly?  If so, would you like to expand your comment into an answer so I can give you the credit for it?

Comment: this is marked as duplicated by Hans Passant, which provided in the other question a very detailed answer that explains these concepts.

Comment: agreed - the answer provided in the other question does answer this question as well.  I did not realize they were so tightly related when I proposed this question, or else I would have just combined them.